# What is the intent of this problem, disguised as an eigenvalue - eigenvector problem?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetry

Let $$ A=
        \begin{bmatrix}
        a & b & c \\
        b & c & a \\
        c & a & b \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$ $a,b,c >0$.

Find eigenvalues and a basis of eigenvectors of the matrix $A$.

My question is: what is the "real" intent of the problem?  I don't think that a direct calculation of $\det(A-\lambda I)$ and solving for its zeroes to find the eigenvalues is a smart move.

The matrix is symmetric, so it is orthogonally diagonalizable.

Also, since it is symmetric, its singular value decomposition is, in fact, its eigendecomposition, so, the singular values of $A =$ the eigenvalues of $A$.

But, the singular values of A is gotten by computing the square root of the eigenvalues of $A^*A$ (or $A^TA$ if the ground field is the set of real numbers.)  So, computing the SVD doesn't appear to be any easier than direct calculation of $\det{(A-\lambda I)}$.

Finally, I'm not sure how to utilize the assumption that $a,b,c >0.$

Comment: 1st step http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=characteristic+polynomial+%7B%7Ba%2Cb%2Cc%7D%2C%7Bb%2Cc%2Ca%7D%2C%7Bc%2Cb%2Ca%7D%7D

Comment: 2nd http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factorice+characteristic+polynomial+%7B%7Ba%2Cb%2Cc%7D%2C%7Bb%2Cc%2Ca%7D%2C%7Bc%2Cb%2Ca%7D%7D

Comment: @janmarqz: The 3rd row of that matrix is $c, a, b$ not $c,b,a$.

Comment: Symmetry suggest one eigenvector $(1,1,1)$.

Comment: This is also a circulant matrix: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CirculantMatrix.html

Although I don't know if thats any useful.

Comment: See [Eigenvectors and eigenvalues of circulant matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix#Eigenvectors_and_eigenvalues)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Note that all row-sums are $a+b+c$.  This gives you one eigenvector and eigenvalue. The other two are not as nice.

EDIT: Perhaps the question was intended to be about
$$ \pmatrix{a & b & c\cr c & a & b\cr b & c & a\cr} $$

Comment: Hi, Professor Israel:  hmm... calling your suggested matrix B, then det(B) = -det(A), from interchanging rows two and three.  Perhaps the computation of det(B) is nicer.  I will try this now.  Thanks for the hint :-)

Comment: Hi, Professor Israel:  did I interpret your hint correctly?  So, compute the determinant of the matrix you suggested; this determinant is the negative of the determinant of A, from the row operation.  Now with this result, try to factorize it, using the identity suggested by WillJagy, and the factors will be the eigenvalues, since the determinant of A is the product of its eigenvalues.  (So, proceeding blindly, as suggested by par, i.e., computing det[A-$\lambda$I] is not the best way to solve this problem.)  Thanks, @RobertIsrael.

Comment: Hi, Professor Israel:  I have a product factorization of det(A) as: -(a+b+c)$(a^2 + b^2 + c^2 - bc - ca - ab)$, which means (a+b+c) is one eigenvalue of A and $(a^2 + b^2 + c^2 - bc - ca - ab)$ is the other eigenvalue.  Is it possible that A has only two eigenvalues (instead of three), with the second one having geometric multiplicity = 2?  Thanks,

Comment: All the determinant tells you is the  **product** of the eigenvalues.  A particular factorization does not necessarily correspond to the individual eigenvalues.  There are three  eigenvalues in this case.  One does happen to be $a+b+c$.  The product of the two others is...

Comment: Hi @RobertIsrael, how do we know that there are three eigenvalues in this  case -- so that knowing (a+b+c) is one eigenvalue (by inspection of the matrix), we can conclude the other factor must be a product of *two* eigenvalues, and not a single *second* eigenvalue with geometric multiplicity = two?  I'm revisiting this problem, because apparently it is not a circulant matrix, so my computations are incorrect.  Thanks,

Comment: Actually it **could** be  a single second eigenvalue with multiplicity $2$.  That would be the case if $a=b=c$.  In fact the discriminant of the characteristic polynomial turns out to be $36 (a^2 + b^2 + c^2 - ab - ac - bc)(ab + ac + bc)$.  There are three distinct eigenvalues when this is nonzero.

Comment: Ok, got it - thanks so much, Professor Israel :-)

Answer (score 4):

Proceeding "blindly" by way of finding the roots of the characteristic
polynomial yields $$\lambda_{0}=a+b+c$$ and $$\lambda_{\pm}=\pm\sqrt{a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2}-ab-ac-bc}.$$
The fact that $a,b,c>0$ was not used.

Perhaps this is just an exercise in noting that Hermitian matrices have real eigenvalues?

Comment: Ok, thanks @par.  Yes, I would consider this method "proceeding blindly" also, and I have already done it, just to see how bad and messy the result can be.  It's made all OK with the identity suggested by WillJagy (see below).  But perhaps computing the determinant (not det[A-$\lambda$I]), and factorizing it is the better way to go ...I will try this now.  Thanks again :-)

Comment: Hi @par, the det(A) is the factorization (a+b+c)$(a^2 + b^2 + c^2 - bc - ca - ab)$; since the determinant is the product of A's eigenvalues, and we know that a+b+c is one eigenvalue, then the other eigenvalue must be $(a^2 + b^2 + c^2 - bc - ca - ab)$.  Why do you put a square root on this number, creating two eigenvalues?  Isn't it possible for it to be one eigenvalue of *geometric* multiplicity = two, so that A is still diagonalizable?  Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

This problem is about geometry. The matrix that is given to you can represent a [quadric](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadrique) surface. One eigenvector can be easily reasoning in terms of simmetry: (1,1,1).

Answer (score 2):

Don't understand your reluctance. As in Robert's answer, there is a famous identity, well worth memorizing,
$$ a^3 + b^3 + c^3 - 3abc = (a+b+c)\left(a^2 + b^2 + c^2 - bc - ca - ab \right). $$

Meanwhile, 
$$ a^2 + b^2 + c^2 - bc - ca - ab = \frac{1}{2} \left( \; (b-c)^2 + (c-a)^2 + (a-b)^2 \; \right) $$
is semidefinite positive, it cannot be negative and is only zero when $a=b=c.$

Now, as in the answer by par, your original, symmetric, matrix has trace $a+b+c,$ meaning the remaining eigenvalues come in a $\pm $ pair, product $-\left( \; (b-c)^2 + (c-a)^2 + (a-b)^2 \; \right)$

Comment: Hi @WillJagy, I may have interpreted Professor Israel's hint incorrectly.  I still carried out the computation of det[A-$\lambda$I], but also used the identity that you have suggested (so (a-$\lambda$) plays the role of "a" in the identity); then I get three eigenvalues: (i) a+b+c (ii) a-b (iii) a-c.  What do you think?  Or am I still missing the point?  Another thing that just occurred to me was to consider two equations: trace A = sum of the eigenvalues, determinant A = product of eigenvalues, but I don't know if heading in this direction is useful...thanks,

Comment: hmm...I'm going to start over and use the identity you gave, compute the determinant of A, and then read off the factors as the eigenvalues, since the determinant is the product of the eigenvalues...

Answer (score 2):

This is a nice problem, that leads to a lot of nice & useful theory, but a little bit of a teaser if the only math exposure you have is just linear algebra.  Note that each row is a cyclic permutation of the row above, e.g. row 2 is the left rotation of row 1 where the "left over" entry, an "a" cycles back to the right. A matrix with this property is call a circulant matrix. Wiki discusses these [in detail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix), and you'd be a better person from *meditating on this page a bit*.  Among many other properties, for a circulant matrix of any size all of the eigenvalues and eigenvectors can be computed explicitly.

Comment: Ok, thanks so much @Tom.  I will study the circulant matrix now - I looked over the Wiki page briefly last night, and am still trying to solve the problem from the point of view that I don't know that this is a special matrix.  (And yes, you are correct, I am preparing for a Linear Algebra exam that doesn't assume any advanced knowledge, of, say, Numerical Analysis material.) Then I'll compute the problem once again, with the explicit formulas given on the Wiki page :-)

Comment: Hi @Tom, I revisited this problem last night and the matrix turns out to be *anti-circulant* - a type of Hankel matrix.  So, the eigenvalue and eigenvector formulas do not apply :(

Comment: (it has constant diagonals from right to left, which is a Hankel matrix, while a circulant matrix has constant diagonals from left to right.)